# Rails how to realize product model and description

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

i want to create a shop like application in rails, with products.
These products have a description in more than one language.

I'm not sure what is the "best" way to realize it.

Should i create 2 models (Product and ProductDescription)
or put it all together in one model?

Has somebody experience what could be a good and clean way for this?

UPDATE:

I don't know if this is a good solution, but it works.

in Product Model:

```
def self.set_language(language)
    @@language = language
end

def title    
  read_attribute("title_#{@@language}")
end
```

in the application_controller

```
before_filter :set_language

private

def set_language
    Product.set_language('en')
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The first choice, you can user I18n, but that is more applicable when the contents are constant, like the title and label on your web page.
2. Or, you can have multiple columns like description_en, description_fr, description_jp in your products table, and attach the params[:locale] in every request.

eg, if params[:locale]=='jp', you just fetch the content of description_jp, so in your controller, you can write like:

```
def show
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  @locale = params[:locale]
end
```

and in your view:

```
<p>
 <%= @product.send("description_#{@locale}") %>
</p>
```

and how to set locale param? I suggest you to read this section.
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-url-params

Hope it can help you!

Comment: Not sure that <%= @product.description_#{@locale} %> is going to work! you probably meant <%= @product.send("description_#{@locale}") %>

Comment: Thanks for your correction Sanghi, it was my mistake. Fixed it!

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to overwrite the "normal" description attribute in the model. So when i call @product.description, the description from the matching locale is loaded (like your example above)?

Comment: yes, you can overwrite the "description" method in the model. But I don't know how could check the params[:locale] in model. I can only get it in controller. But I think there must be a way to do that in model.

Comment: Thanky for help, it works now.
I updated the answer with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into i18n (Internationalization)

Check out the Guides about it [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html).

Comment: The description sould be editable in the admin backend, so it need to be stored in the database.